# multiple colors on beanplot in R

Tags: r, colors, plot

I have created a bean plot in R using the following

```
beanplot(windA, side='both', border='NA', 
        col=list('gray',c('red','white')),
        ylab='Wind Speed (m/s)' ,what=c(1,1,1,0),xaxt ='n')

axis(1,at=c(1:12),labels =c  ('Jan','Feb','Mar','apr','may','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'))
legend('topright', fill=c('gray','red'), legend= c('Measured', 'calc'))
```

and I get the following image[image]

Is there a way that I can alternate the colors?  For example, can I get Jan to be gray and red then Feb to be gray and blue and continue this alternating color scheme for the year?

Comment: It's helpful if you include a small sample dataset so that your example is reproducible. This is especially important for the first parameter because depending on the class of `windA` the function may do very different things. Also, when using function that are not in base R, be clear about what package you a are loading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could specify the color order you want, `col=list('gray','red','grey','blue')`, using a sample dataset `USArrests` from base `R`, the colors are cycled till all the points are plotted

```
require(beanplot)
beanplot(USJudgeRatings, side='both', border='NA', 
          col=list('gray','red','grey','blue'),
          ylab='US Judge Ratings' ,what=c(1,1,1,0),xaxt ='n')
```

[image]