# Colour individual lines in beanplot

Tags: r, colors

I would like to change the colors of the individual lines in a beanplot. Using col, I can change the color of the bean area, all lines inside the bean, all lines outside the bean, and average line per bean. I would like to assign different colors to different lines depending on a variable.

```
x <- rnorm(15)
beanplot(x,ll = 1, col = c(0,1,1,2),
                 side = "both", axes = FALSE,method = "stack")
```

I would like to assign colors based on the vector colpref

```
colpref <- c(5, 5, 3, 5, 5, 3, 5, 5, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3)
```

Comment: not sure but would this post help you?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23497238/multiple-colors-on-beanplot-in-r

Answer (score 4):

you can probably play with the parameter `add` and `what` like this

```
beanplot(x[colpref==3],ll = 1, col = c(0,3,3,3), what=c(1,0,1,1),
         side = "both", axes = FALSE,method = "stack", add=FALSE)
beanplot(x[colpref==5],ll = 1, col = c(0,5,5,5), what=c(1,0,1,1),
         side = "both", axes = FALSE,method = "stack", add=TRUE)
beanplot(x,ll = 1, col = c(0,5,5,5), what=c(0,1,0,0),
         side = "both", axes = FALSE,method = "stack", add=TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: ah, I thought op meant assigning colors individually to all the line segments in what == 4. I was busy hacking the source code. this makes more sense