# Colour individual lines and OVERALLLINE in beanplot

Tags: r, colors

I had difficulty in assigning a color to each individual line in Beanplot in R and finally, I found a good solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29968843/colour-individual-lines-in-beanplot/29969382#29969382). I would like to extend the question and ask if there is any way to either remove the overallline or possibly color it based on each group of data (i.e. for blue lines be blue, this is the best for me). It seems there is no method or attibute for this, based on [Here.](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/beanplot/beanplot.pdf)

I use the same example with minor changes:

```
library(beanplot)
x <- rnorm(15)
colpref <- c(5, 5, 3, 5, 5, 3, 5, 5, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3)
beanplot(x[colpref==3],ll = 1, col = c(0,3,3,3), what=c(1,0,1,1),axes = FALSE,method = "stack", add=FALSE)
beanplot(x[colpref==5],ll = 1, col = c(0,5,5,5), what=c(1,0,1,1), axes = FALSE,method = "stack", add=TRUE)
beanplot(x,ll = 1, col = c(0,5,5,5), what=c(0,1,0,0), axes = FALSE,method = "stack", add=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to turn the overallline off, it is done by putting 0 for the first element of what as follows, but still looking forward to making it colorful.

```
beanplot(x[colpref==3],ll = 1, col = c(0,3,3,3), what=c(0,0,1,1),axes = 
FALSE,method = "stack", add=FALSE)
beanplot(x[colpref==5],ll = 1, col = c(0,5,5,5), what=c(0,0,1,1), axes = FALSE,method = "stack", add=TRUE)
beanplot(x,ll = 1, col = c(0,5,5,5), what=c(0,1,0,0), axes = FALSE,method = "stack", add=TRUE)
```